How to properly instrument `Box<dyn Future<...>>`
I'm adding tracing to my application with quite a bit of legacy code. I've added lots of traces so far but having trouble with a few patterns. One pattern I'm having trouble with is the following

    #[tracing::instrument(skip_all)]
    pub(crate) fn blocks_matching_polling_intervals(
        &self,
        logger: Logger,
        from: i32,
        to: i32,
        filter: &EthereumBlockFilter,
    ) -> Pin<
        Box<
            dyn std::future::Future<Output = Result<Vec<EthereumTrigger>, anyhow::Error>>
                + std::marker::Send,
        >,
    > {
        // Create a HashMap of block numbers to Vec<EthereumBlockTriggerType>
        let matching_blocks = (from..=to)
            .filter_map(|block_number| {
                filter
                    .polling_intervals
                    .iter()
                    .find_map(|(start_block, interval)| {
                        let has_once_trigger = (*interval == 0) && (block_number == *start_block);
                        let has_polling_trigger = block_number >= *start_block
                            && *interval > 0
                            && ((block_number - start_block) % *interval) == 0;

                        if has_once_trigger || has_polling_trigger {
                            let mut triggers = Vec::new();
                            if has_once_trigger {
                                triggers.push(EthereumBlockTriggerType::Start);
                            }
                            if has_polling_trigger {
                                triggers.push(EthereumBlockTriggerType::End);
                            }
                            Some((block_number, triggers))
                        } else {
                            None
                        }
                    })
            })
            .collect::<HashMap<_, _>>();

        let blocks_matching_polling_filter = self.load_ptrs_for_blocks(
            logger.clone(),
            matching_blocks.iter().map(|(k, _)| *k).collect_vec(),
        );

        let block_futures = blocks_matching_polling_filter.map(move |ptrs| {
            ptrs.into_iter()
                .flat_map(|ptr| {
                    let triggers = matching_blocks
                        .get(&ptr.number)
                        // Safe to unwrap since we are iterating over ptrs which was created from
                        // the keys of matching_blocks
                        .unwrap()
                        .iter()
                        .map(move |trigger| EthereumTrigger::Block(ptr.clone(), trigger.clone()));

                    triggers
                })
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        });

        block_futures.compat().boxed()
    }

    #[tracing::instrument(skip_all)]
    pub(crate) fn block_range_to_ptrs(
        &self,
        logger: Logger,
        from: BlockNumber,
        to: BlockNumber,
    ) -> Box<dyn Future<Item = Vec<BlockPtr>, Error = Error> + Send> {
        // Currently we can't go to the DB for this because there might be duplicate entries for
        // the same block number.
        debug!(&logger, "Requesting hashes for blocks [{}, {}]", from, to);
        Box::new(
            self.load_block_ptrs_rpc(logger, (from..=to).collect())
                .collect(),
        )
    }

    fn load_block_ptrs_rpc(
        &self,
        logger: Logger,
        block_nums: Vec<BlockNumber>,
    ) -> impl Stream<Item = BlockPtr, Error = Error> + Send {
        let web3 = self.web3.clone();

        stream::iter_ok::<_, Error>(block_nums.into_iter().map(move |block_num| {
            let span = info_span!("load_block_ptrs_rpc");
            let web3 = web3.clone();
            retry(format!("load block ptr {}", block_num), &logger)
                .no_limit()
                .timeout_secs(ENV_VARS.json_rpc_timeout.as_secs())
                .run(move || {
                    let web3 = web3.clone();
                    async move {
                        let block = web3
                            .eth()
                            .block(BlockId::Number(Web3BlockNumber::Number(block_num.into())))
                            .boxed()
                            .await?;

                        block.ok_or_else(|| {
                            anyhow!("Ethereum node did not find block {:?}", block_num)
                        })
                    }
                })
                .instrument(span)
                .boxed()
                .compat()
                .from_err()
        }))
        .buffered(ENV_VARS.block_batch_size)
        .map(|b| b.into())
    }

blocks_matching_polling_intervals calls block_range_to_ptrs which then calls load_block_ptrs_rpc. The first two functions have the #instrument attribute while the third function manually manages spans. I'm finding that when I run this, the spans that are generated do not have the proper parent-child relationships.

In the above screenshot we can see that blocks_matching_polling_intervals and block_range_to_ptrs both complete in ~60us and that load_block_ptrs_rpc is not a child of block_range_to_ptrs as it should be.
How can I properly instrument blocks_matching_polling_intervals and block_range_to_ptrs? I've tried several variants of using the .instrument() combinator and manually creating/entering spans but none of worked well.

You already got an answer on how to instrument futures.

that solution worked for different patterns but doesn't seem to work here unfortunately. Realdebill's solution helped me instrument another ~10 functions but I still have a few more left that I need to instrument which don't match the pattern he's suggested.

What exactly is the problem with it here?

The pattern of adding a .instrument combinator doesn't get the spans to 1. last longer than a few microseconds and 2. often doesn't compile and 3. doesn't set up the proper parent child relationships for spans

turns out I needed to add the futures-01 feature to the tracing-futures crate and then the .instrument combinator worked perfectly for block_range_to_ptrs
